# Calling Polymorphic Scala Methods from Java

Tags: java, scala, interop, polymorphism

I am writing an API that I want to be usable from both Scala and Java.  I have a polymorphic method defined in a Scala class, and I am having trouble calling it from Java.

According to this interoperability [FAQ](http://www.scala-lang.org/faq/4) at scala-lang.org, using a Scala class that uses advanced language features "can be tricky" *but it does not say it is impossible*.  Since how Scala's advanced features translate to Java is not documented, it suggests disassembling the class file to experiment with how it works.

**Example Code**

```
class Polymorphic {
  def polyMethod[T](implicit om: Manifest[T]) = {
    println(om.erasure.getName)
    om.erasure.newInstance
  }
}

object Polymorphic {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val objOfT = (new Polymorphic).polyMethod[String]
  }
}
```

This works fine in scala, printing "`java.lang.String`"

I ran `javap -c` on the resulting class file and got the following listing for `polyMethod`:

```
public java.lang.Object polyMethod(scala.reflect.Manifest);
  Code:
   0:   getstatic   #20; //Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
   3:   aload_1
   4:   invokeinterface #27,  1; //InterfaceMethod scala/reflect/ClassManifest.erasure:()Ljava/lang/Class;
   9:   invokevirtual   #33; //Method java/lang/Class.getName:()Ljava/lang/String;
   12:  invokevirtual   #37; //Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   15:  aload_1
   16:  invokeinterface #27,  1; //InterfaceMethod scala/reflect/ClassManifest.erasure:()Ljava/lang/Class;
   21:  invokevirtual   #41; //Method java/lang/Class.newInstance:()Ljava/lang/Object;
   24:  areturn
```

3 Major Problems:

1. The method is polymorphic in its return type
2. The `Manifest` parameter is not implicit in Java
3. I can't actually pass the type parameter.

The real project code I'm trying to do this with is here:
https://github.com/ConnorDoyle/EnMAS/blob/master/clientServerPrototype/src/org/enmas/pomdp/State.scala

My ultimate goal is a fully generic yet type safe data dictionary.  It works great in Scala, but I would really like to be able to call this method from the Java API as well.  My design motivation is to keep reflection, explicit casting, and null checks out of the client code.

**Edit: 18 Nov 2011** *In response to comment by @kassens below*

Changing the definition of `polyMethod` to the following:

```
def polyMethod[T](implicit om: Manifest[T]): T = {
  println(om.erasure.getName)
  om.erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

gives the exact same byte code when I inspect the class file with `javap`.

Comment: The method it *not* polymorphic in its return type. The static return type is `Any`: http://pastie.org/2881692

Comment: @kassens: Thanks. I addressed your comment with an edit, but I don't think it gets at the root problem.

Comment: Just a comment, if you intend to look at bytecode a lot, look at JAD: http://www.varaneckas.com/jad which gives java as output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems at play:

1. Unified generics in Scala. The fact that `T` is unbounded in Scala (meaning it can be instantiated with primitive types), makes the Scala compiler conservatively erase it to `Object`. If you change your scala code to

   ```
   def polyMethod[T <: AnyRef](implicit om: Manifest[T]) = {
      println(om.erasure.getName)
      om.erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T]
   }
   ```

   it will return T. Note the explicit cast from `newInstance`, since the Scala library method does not return the correct generic type.
2. Using Manifests. This adds another layer of generics that you need to align in order to make your call pass. As didierd suggested, better have an overload in Scala that takes a `java.lang.Class` instead.

So my advice would be to add this in your Scala code:

```
  def polyMethod[T <: AnyRef](cls: Class[T]): T = 
    polyMethod(Manifest.classType(cls))
```

And then call it this way from Java:

```
void test(Polymorphic p) { 
    JavaScalaCall c = p.polyMethod(this.getClass());
}
```

As a side note, the bytecode is always erased. If you want to see the generic information in classfiles, look for the Signature attribute using, for instance, [jclasslib](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jclasslib/overview.html).

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent in java of having a manifest argument is to pass the class (explicitly alas, and it does not work too well when the type you want is a generic type).

It would be possible to create the manifest from java, but better to do that from scala. 
You can add

```
def polyMethodForJava[T](clazz: Class[T]) 
  = polyMethod(ClassManifest.From(clazz))
```

Of course, it won't be as comfortable to use as it is in scala.

Comment: Indeed, another approach I was considering is the one found scattered throughout the standard library: accepting a dummy prototype object as a parameter.  Either way however, the responsibility still lies with the author of the call-site code to explicitly cast the result properly.  Perhaps this is an unavoidable deficiency of the Java language as it currently exists.

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly some Scala methods that can't be called from Java. See [here](http://www.tikalk.com/incubator/blog/creating-java-api-scala-using-bridge) for a description of one example (not the one you've run into).

In general, if you want to create an interface that can be consumed "naturally" by a Java client, you'll probably need to write some adapter classes or methods.

Comment: Hmm -- that `@bridge` annotation is pretty cool, I will probably end up using that.  At this point it seems the magic glue to get this to work will not be as pretty as the pure Scala API and I would rather not pollute it.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to use Java generic type, and Box/Unbox your own data type. Use type match to do your operation.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain a little more what you mean by this?

Comment: Please refer to this Java Box/Unbox page: [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/BoxingandUnboxing.htm)

Comment: I understand the general idea of how boxing works in Java, but I'm not seeing how it helps in this instance.  Sorry, maybe I'm missing something.